# Alternative Clojure Threading Macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm having a little trouble with a threading macro I'm trying to write. I've posted a stripped down version to show what problem I'm having.

```
(defmacro <->
  [v & fs]
  `(do
    (-> ~v ~@fs)
    ~v))
```

The macro is equivalent to the thread first -> macro, but instead of returning the result of the threading operation, it returns the original value it was passed.

The trouble, I'm having is that when I do something like:

```
(<-> 1 
     (<-> println)
     (<-> println))
```

I would expect the output to be

```
1
1
=> 1
```

but because the macro evaluates outside in, the macroexpand looks like:

```
(do 
  (do 
    (println 
      (do 
        (println 1) 
        1)) 
    (do 
      (println 1) 
      1)) 1)
```

and the result is

```
1
1
1
=> 1
```

I can see why this is happening since the macro is evaluated from outside in, but I'm not sure how to fix it so the macro actually works as expected (i.e. evaluating the value v before threading it to the next form).

Comment: Btw, what you're trying to achieve sounds like the `doto` macro. Maybe give its source a look over.

Comment: Thats a helpful function i didn't know about, but I'm not sure it threads results...it looks like each form takes the initial value rather than the value generated by the previous form

Comment: You can combine them in lots of ways to get both threading and side effects. `(doto x (-> (f) (println)) (-> (g) (println)))` expands to `(let [x# x] (println (f x#)) (println (g x#)) x#)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your macro expands to a form in which its `v` argument is evaluated twice.  You need to evaluate `v` only once, and `let`-bind the result so you can refer to that value later.

```
(defmacro <-> [v & fs]
  (let [$v (gensym "$v_")]
    `(let [~$v ~v]
       (-> ~$v ~@fs)
       ~$v)))
```

Note the use of `gensym` to generate a fresh symbol.

Comment: I think I was actually understanding my mistake incorrectly, this clarifies it, thanks